# excel last auto save is a month old

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I was working on an Microsoft Excel 2010 document when all of a sudden my computer either crashed or rebooted I'm not sure exactly all I know is when it finally turned back on my document last auto save was from one month ago and I lost everything in between.
Is there any other recovery utility I could use, I don't understand why the autosave is so old. I do not have a system restore point.

Answer (score 2):

As a last resort you might check in `C:\Users\\[YOUR_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel`

Otherwise there is no possible way to recover a file that was never saved to a physical drive.

As for the future you might try this:

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Options.
3. Click Save.
4. Make sure the Save AutoRecover information every *x* minutes check box
   is selected.
5. make sure the **Keep the last autosaved version if I close without
   saving** check box is selected in Excel.

Better yet hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> frequently and you won't have to rely on autosaves.